# Polars replace_time_zone and convert_time_zone show different string representation for same timezone conversion

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, python-polars

Test Data:

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, time, datetime

# polars df for Jan to 12th, March 2022 before DST transition.
tdf = pl.DataFrame(
    pl.date_range(
        low=date(2022, 1, 3),
        high=date(2022, 3, 12),
        interval="5m",
        time_unit="ns",
        time_zone="UTC",
    ).alias("UTC")
)
```

My use case is to convert UTC data (or timezone-unaware) to EST/EDT data (or timezone-aware), then filter the data on a time range (9:30 to 16:00).

```
tz_replaced_filtered = tdf.with_columns( 
    pl.col("UTC").dt.replace_time_zone(time_zone="US/Eastern").alias("NY")
).filter(
  pl.col("NY").cast(pl.Time).is_between(time(9), time(16), closed="both")
)

# output
shape: (5780, 2)
┌─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ UTC                     ┆ NY                       │
│ ---                     ┆ ---                      │
│ datetime[ns, UTC]       ┆ datetime[ns, US/Eastern] │
╞═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 2022-01-03 04:00:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 04:00:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 04:05:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 04:05:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 04:10:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 04:10:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 04:15:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 04:15:00 EST  │
│ …                       ┆ …                        │
│ 2022-03-11 10:45:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 10:45:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 10:50:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 10:50:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 10:55:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 10:55:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 11:00:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 11:00:00 EST  │
└─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

Apparently there's no obvious 9 to 16 time range in this resulted `df`.

I probed further:

```
tz_replaced_filtered.with_columns(
   pl.col("NY").cast(pl.Time).alias("NY_TIME"),
   pl.col("UTC").cast(pl.Time).alias("UTC_TIME")
)

# output
shape: (5780, 4)
┌─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ UTC                     ┆ NY                       ┆ NY_TIME  ┆ UTC_TIME │
│ ---                     ┆ ---                      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[ns, UTC]       ┆ datetime[ns, US/Eastern] ┆ time     ┆ time     │
╞═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 2022-01-03 04:00:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 04:00:00 EST  ┆ 09:00:00 ┆ 04:00:00 │
│ 2022-01-03 04:05:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 04:05:00 EST  ┆ 09:05:00 ┆ 04:05:00 │
│ 2022-01-03 04:10:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 04:10:00 EST  ┆ 09:10:00 ┆ 04:10:00 │
│ 2022-01-03 04:15:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 04:15:00 EST  ┆ 09:15:00 ┆ 04:15:00 │
│ …                       ┆ …                        ┆ …        ┆ …        │
│ 2022-03-11 10:45:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 10:45:00 EST  ┆ 15:45:00 ┆ 10:45:00 │
│ 2022-03-11 10:50:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 10:50:00 EST  ┆ 15:50:00 ┆ 10:50:00 │
│ 2022-03-11 10:55:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 10:55:00 EST  ┆ 15:55:00 ┆ 10:55:00 │
│ 2022-03-11 11:00:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 11:00:00 EST  ┆ 16:00:00 ┆ 11:00:00 │
└─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

The underlying timestamps does seem to show that I succeed in filtering on time range 9 to 16; and it is only the string representation which isn't in sync.

```
 tdf.with_columns(
     pl.col("UTC").dt.replace_time_zone(time_zone="US/Eastern").alias("NY_REPLACED"),
     pl.col("UTC").dt.convert_time_zone(time_zone="US/Eastern").alias("NY_CONVERTED")
 )

# output
shape: (19585, 3)
┌─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ UTC                     ┆ NY_REPLACED              ┆ NY_CONVERTED             │
│ ---                     ┆ ---                      ┆ ---                      │
│ datetime[ns, UTC]       ┆ datetime[ns, US/Eastern] ┆ datetime[ns, US/Eastern] │
╞═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 2022-01-03 00:00:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 00:00:00 EST  ┆ 2022-01-02 19:00:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 00:05:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 00:05:00 EST  ┆ 2022-01-02 19:05:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 00:10:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 00:10:00 EST  ┆ 2022-01-02 19:10:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 00:15:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 00:15:00 EST  ┆ 2022-01-02 19:15:00 EST  │
│ …                       ┆ …                        ┆ …                        │
│ 2022-03-11 23:45:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 23:45:00 EST  ┆ 2022-03-11 18:45:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 23:50:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 23:50:00 EST  ┆ 2022-03-11 18:50:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 23:55:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 23:55:00 EST  ┆ 2022-03-11 18:55:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-12 00:00:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-12 00:00:00 EST  ┆ 2022-03-11 19:00:00 EST  │
└─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

This final step concludes that `replaced_time_zone` and `convert_time_zone` does not generate the same string representation for an identical time zone conversion operation.

More specifically, `replaced_time_zone` does replace the underlying timestamps however it does not "replace" the string representation; what `replaced_time_zone` does on the surface for UTC (or simply timezone-unaware timestamps) is like `with_time_zone`, i.e., simply attaching time zone info to existing time stamps.

I'd appreciate if someone could clarify above.

**Question Background**

This is for polars users and devs such that all questions related to timezone conversion raised by me for `polars` can be easily referenced.

I firstly raised [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165901/polars-add-substract-utc-offset-from-datetime-object) to see how we could filter based on converted timestamps (utc offset accounted for), then as `polars` provided `replace_time_zone` a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793219/polars-replace-time-zone-function-throws-error-of-no-such-local-time) for it is also raised.

A related question metioned by @FObersteiner is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75268283/how-to-truncate-a-datetime-to-just-the-day).

For the time being my understanding is that `replace_time_zone` should provide the same string representation as `convert_time_zone`, because essentially what they are doing it the same. And this would make filtering on date/time range in `polars` WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get).

**Background Information**

`Polars` provides `replace_time_zone` and `convert_time_zone` to handle scenarios like this.

`convert_time_zone` changes only the string representation presented to the user, not the underlying timestamps. Therefore `cast` is not going to work with "converted" timestamps in my use case (filtering would still be on the orignal underlying timestamps).

Regarding `replace_time_zone`, DST transitions is causing [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793219/polars-replace-time-zone-function-throws-error-of-no-such-local-time) when user tries to `replace_time_zone` and this issue seems to be universal given that particular timestamp just doesn't exist because of DST transition:

```
# demo polars df
tpl = pl.DataFrame(
   pl.date_range(
        low=date(2022, 3, 13),
        high=date(2022, 3, 15),
        interval="5m",
        time_unit="ns",
        time_zone="UTC",
   ).alias("UTC")
)

tpl.select(
   pl.col("UTC").dt.replace_time_zone(time_zone="America/New_York").alias("NY")
)

# Panic Exception: no such local time

# demo pandas pf
tpn = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.date_range(start="2022-03-13", 
                  end="2022-03-15",
                  freq="5T", # 5 minute interval
                  tz=None, # default to UTC
                  inclusive="both"),
    columns=["UTC"]
)

tpn.UTC.dt.tz_localize("America/New_York")

# NonExistentTimeError: 2022-03-13 02:00:00
```

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75268283/10197418) is related. And I think `.cast(pl.Time)` should yield *local time*, not the underlying UTC representation. So essentially, it's a bug imho.

Comment: @FObersteiner [v0.16.15](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7735) just added `dt.datetime(), dt.date(), dt.time()` which I think address these issues?

Comment: @jqurious yes, looks good now

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you're running into is that `pl.cast(pl.Time)` doesn't convert to local time.

You probably want to filter using `.dt.hour()`:

```py
In [23]: tz_replaced_filtered.filter(pl.col('NY').dt.hour().is_between(9, 16))
Out[23]:
shape: (6528, 2)
┌─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ UTC                     ┆ NY                       │
│ ---                     ┆ ---                      │
│ datetime[ns, UTC]       ┆ datetime[ns, US/Eastern] │
╞═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 2022-01-03 09:00:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 09:00:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 09:05:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 09:05:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 09:10:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 09:10:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 09:15:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 09:15:00 EST  │
│ …                       ┆ …                        │
│ 2022-03-11 16:40:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 16:40:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 16:45:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 16:45:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 16:50:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 16:50:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 16:55:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 16:55:00 EST  │
└─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

### EDIT

As of Polars 0.16.15, you can use `.dt.time`:

```py
In [12]: tz_replaced_filtered = tdf.with_columns(
    ...:     pl.col("UTC").dt.replace_time_zone(time_zone="US/Eastern").alias("NY")
    ...: ).filter(
    ...:   pl.col("NY").dt.time().is_between(time(9), time(16), closed="both")
    ...: )

In [13]: tz_replaced_filtered
Out[13]:
shape: (5780, 2)
┌─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ UTC                     ┆ NY                       │
│ ---                     ┆ ---                      │
│ datetime[ns, UTC]       ┆ datetime[ns, US/Eastern] │
╞═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 2022-01-03 09:00:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 09:00:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 09:05:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 09:05:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 09:10:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 09:10:00 EST  │
│ 2022-01-03 09:15:00 UTC ┆ 2022-01-03 09:15:00 EST  │
│ …                       ┆ …                        │
│ 2022-03-11 15:45:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 15:45:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 15:50:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 15:50:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 15:55:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 15:55:00 EST  │
│ 2022-03-11 16:00:00 UTC ┆ 2022-03-11 16:00:00 EST  │
└─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```